# Question on Stokes theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have a question relating an identity using Stokes theorem.

$$\iint_A \left( \nabla \otimes \vec{F}\right) \cdot \vec{dA} = \oint_c \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr}$$

But my professor mentioned something about the divergence theorem

$$\int_V \left( \nabla \cdot \vec{F} \right)dV = \oint_{\partial V} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dA}$$

so does this mean I can say:

$$\iint_A \left( \nabla \otimes \vec{F}\right) \cdot \vec{dA} = \oint_c \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr} = \iint_A \left( \nabla \cdot \vec{F} \right) dA$$

Because this would imply:

$$\left( \nabla \otimes \vec{F}\right) \cdot \vec{dA}= \left( \nabla \cdot \vec{F} \right) dA$$

And I don't believe this to be correct. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's wrong because you are equating very different things, used in very different contexts.  In Stokes' Theorem, you are expressing the value of a line integral of the tangential component of a vector field about a closed circuit in terms of the normal component of the curl of that vector field over a "capping" surface of that circuit, which is an open area.  On the other hand, the divergence theorem states that the net flux of the normal component of a vector field through a closed surface is equal to the amount of the divergence of that vector field in the volume defined by that surface.  So the "areas" you are equating cannot be equated: one is open, and one is closed.